# How do I customize the Refinement Panel for the main Site Search Results Page

Tags: search

How do I customize the Refinement Panel for the main Site Search Results Page?

I have successfully achieved this for a Basic Search Centre to allow filtering on Creation Date by editing the web part and editing the Filter Category Definition to include new fields. However, the main Site Search Results Page does not allow me to edit it. Any ideas would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean by the main Site Search Results Page this one: OSSSearchResults.aspx
This page is located in the layouts folder on the file system and not meant to be changed, it's not a webpart page, but a server page. You can create your own search results page and set this page as the 'main' in stead of the OSSSearchResults.aspx page. This is a setting at Site Collection level, Search Settings.

Comment: Is it possible to copy the OSSSearchResults.aspx page when you don't have access to SharePoint Designer of the SharePoint installation ?